# Use NextJS/React Class method in a Function

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

Given

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

class ClientApi {
    API_URL: string = process.env.CLIENT_API_URL;

    client: AxiosInstance;

    constructor() {
        this.client = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.API_URL,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        });
    }

    async doGet(url: string) {
        try {
            // get Authorization Headers, etc.

            return await this.client.get(url,
                authorizationHeaders
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}

export default ClientApi;
```

How do I call doGet() from a function:

```
import doGet from './ClientApi'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Users() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserData();
    }, []);



    return (
        <>
        // render users
        </>
    )

    async function getUserData() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await doGet("/users")
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
            });
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
}
```

There is an error in the IDE on `await doGet("/users")`:
`Value of type 'typeof ClientApi' is not callable`

At runtime: `index.js:654  Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _ClientApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.doPost) is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the *class*. You have to **instantiate** it to call its methods, like:

```
import ClientApi from './ClientApi'

const client = new ClientApi();

...

function getUserData() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    client.doGet("/users")
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data);
        });
    setIsLoading(false);
}
```

But you don't need a class at all, since you won't have different instances of if. Just use a plain function like:

```
import { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

const API_URL = process.env.CLIENT_API_URL;

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
});

export async function doGet(url: string) {
    // get Authorization Headers, etc.
    return await client.get(url, authorizationHeaders);
}
```

In your component:

```
import { doGet } from './api';

...

function getUserData() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    doGet("/users")
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data);
        });
    setIsLoading(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are exporting the class and expecting to get the function directly. What you need to do is you need to instantiate the class before you use it. Hers a guide for [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Here's some demo code to help you understand:

This is your class:

```
    class MyClass {
  age: number;
  constructor(age: number) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  getDoubleAge() {
    return this.age * 2;
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Now for the react component:

```
 import MyClass from './MyClass';
    const MyComponent = () => {
      //this function instantiates MyClass and calls a method
      function myFunction(): number {
        //instance of MyClass
        const myClass = new MyClass(12);
        // call method of MyClass
        return myClass.getDoubleAge();
      }
    
      //this displays 24
      return <div>{myFunction()}</div>;
    };
    
    export default MyComponent;
```

So the class object must be created to access its member methods. Cheers :)